# Angular2 configuration data with transform

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, angular, web.config-transform

I am creating an Angular2 application that will be using a webApi.  What is the best practice for handling configuration data?  I would like a way to do a transform as I deploy to different environments.

When working locally the webApi will be local such as: http://localhost:64551/Api/person.

In Dev it will be:
http://devServer.com/Api/person

Prod will be:
http://prodServer.com/Api/person

I can't hard-code the server name.  I need it in a configuration, but it will change as we deploy to different environments.

This is an Anglar2 project that I am building inside an ASP.net 5 project using Visual Studio.
The WebApi is an ASP.net 5 project.
I will be hosting at Azure.

In the past, I have used web.config transforms but that's not an option for the angular app.

Any advice?

Comment: is your angular app and the api served form the same server? if so you can just use `window.location.origin` and it will change between those three values depending on where it is running

Comment: No.  The webApi app will be it's on project.  That is what causes the problem.  If it was the same project I could just use a relative api name.

Comment: I have the same problem and probably this can be solved by using host name and private virtual networks. In this case the front end app the host name (i.e. mybackendserver/api/person)  and not the pubblic IP address

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using API requests to retrieve configuration during bootstrap of your angular application. I personally believe that Angular should take this approach because requiring developers to build for each environment isn't the best solution.

Using Configuration Files in Assets:

Create different configuration folders/files like so

- /assets/configurations/develop/configuration.json
- /assets/configurations/production/configuration.json

Populate those configuration.json files with the correct values.

```
{
  "production": false,
  "api": "https://dev.myapi.domain.com"
}
```

Create an interface that represents your configuration

```
export interface InitConfiguration {
  production: boolean;
  api: string;
}
```

Update your angular.json (or workspace.json or project.json) file so that serving will utilize the correct file. This example uses a shared lib that stores assets and pulls them in. Make sure to apply the glob to every environment, below only shows dev.

```
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "configurations": {
        "dev": {
          "assets": [
            {
              "glob": "**/*",
              "input": "./libs/shared/assets/",
              "output": "./assets"
            },
            {
              "glob": "configuration.json",
              "input": "./libs/shared/assets/configurations/develop",
              "output": "./assets/configurations"
            }
            ...
```

This moves the asset to the location that the service will use to retrieve the json.

Create a Configuration Service that utilizes XMLHttpRequest (can't inject http as it will need to run before angular is bootstrapped). Note how the get request is accessing the assets/configuration/configuration.json file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { InitConfiguration } from './init-configuration';

/**
 * Service that provides configuration information from assets
 * Assets folder contains \{env}\configuration.json file that matches environment
 */
// @dynamic
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class InitConfigurationService<
  T extends InitConfiguration = InitConfiguration
  > {
  private static _configuration: InitConfiguration | undefined = undefined;
  static production = false;

  static loadConfig(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.addEventListener('load', () => {
        if (req.status === 200) {
          try {
            InitConfigurationService._configuration = JSON.parse(
              req.responseText
            );
            this.production =
              InitConfigurationService._configuration?.production || false;
          } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
          }
          resolve();
        } else {
          reject(req.statusText);
        }
      });
      req.open('GET', '/assets/configurations/configuration.json');
      req.send();
    });
  }

  getConfiguration(): T {
    if (!InitConfigurationService._configuration) {
      throw new ReferenceError(
        `Attempting to access configuration before it is set.
         Possible Solutions:
          1. Bootstrap the loadConfig method into your applications main.ts
          InitConfigurationService.loadConfig().then(
            () => {
              return platformBrowserDynamic()
                .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
                .catch((err) => console.error(err));
            }
          )
        `
      );
    }
    return InitConfigurationService._configuration as T;
  }

  get production(): boolean {
    return InitConfigurationService.production;
  }

  get api(): string {
    return this.getConfiguration().api || '';
  }
}
```

Finally bootstrap the service to run loadConfig() before the bootstrapModule is called

```
InitConfigurationService.loadConfig().then(async () => {
  if (InitConfigurationService.production) {
    enableProdMode();
  }
  try {
    return platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  } catch (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
});
```

These steps support serving up different environments with different serve configurations. When you go to deploy you will need to manually move the file. That's as simple as introducing a step in your CD similar to this.

```
copy my-angular-app\assets\configurations\develop\configuration.json my-angular-app\assets\configurations\configuration.json /Y
```

Answer (score -1):

- Add multiple solution configurations from visual studio - `debug, qa, prod`
- Inside your `app/` folder add environment specific config files

  - environment.debug.ts
  - environment.qa.ts
  - environment.prod.ts
- Inside `app/` folder add `environment.ts` file. Add your configuration data there. Import this file into different components for use.
- To include environment specific config file, add a script in prebuild event of project from visual studio project properties

`xcopy "app\config\environment.$(ConfigurationName).ts" "app\environment.ts" /Y`